# Clear Inline CSS using Jquery: background-color

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a class that I add the background colour to using Jquery, however I'm having issues getting the value of the colour once it's set, it just keeps coming up as `undefined`

My code so far

```
// Highlight Paid
function highlightPaid() {
    var color = $(this).closest(".course-paid").css("background-color");
    alert(color);
    if(color === undefined) {
        $('.course-paid').css("background-color","#F3F315");
    } else {
        if(rgb2hex(color)=='#F3F315') {
            $('.course-paid').css("background-color","transparent");
        } else {
            $('.course-paid').css("background-color","#F3F315");
        }
    }
}
// Convert RGB to HEX
function rgb2hex(rgb){
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb((d+),s*(d+),s*(d+))$/);
    return "#" + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this and/or make this code better?

**EDIT**

Ok so I have some divs with the class `course-paid` on them, then I have a button on my page, that when I click it I want to toggle the background colour on the divs that have that class. So if it doesn't have a background colour I want it to have the value `#F3F315` and if it has that colour I want to remove the background colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code

```
function highlightPaid() {
    $('.course-paid').each(function( i ) {
        if (this.style.backgroundColor == '') {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#F3F315";
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
    });         
}
```